# Concatenating strings containing NULL values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to concatenate a string

I want output like this:

```
NEX-SYM-VIM-CRE
```

If the input is `NEX-NULL-NULL-VRE`, it comes out to be `NEX---CRE` or `---CRE` or `NEX---`  as i have replaced `NULL` with `-`

But concatenation to get a final result like `NEX-SYM` is not coming

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
ISNULL(NEX,'-') + '-' + ISNULL(SYM,'-') + '-' + ISNULL(VIM,'-') + '-' + ISNULL(CRE,'-')
```

Comment: Lol, i'm not sure I did, but sometimes you gotta go with your gut :)

Answer (score 2):

Always add a `-` delimiting character to the right but only when there is a value:

```
NULLIF(
       COALESCE(NEX + '-', '') 
          + COALESCE(SYM + '-', '') 
          + COALESCE(VIM + '-', '') 
          + COALESCE(CRE + '-', ''), ''
      )
```

then you always need to trim the last character (will be a `-` delimiting character) unless the result is `NULL`.